# Storyboard navigation - pushing and removing from stack

Tags: ios, storyboard

I have two storyboards in the same ios application.

Storyboard 1 is the login.storyboard.
Storybaord 2 is the processing.storyboard.

login.storyboard has the following scenes:

1) welcome

2) login

processing.storyboard has

1) start

2) images

3) description

4) finish

login.storyboard handles login whilst processing.storyboard creates and object for uploading.

My understanding of the stack is as follows:

Navigate from welcome to login gives:

```
1:[welcome]-[login.storyboard]

2:[login]-[login.storyboard]
```

after login I push the processing.storyboard using

```
- (void) pushStory: (NSString *) story {

UIStoryboard *settingsStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:story bundle:nil];
UIViewController *initialSettingsVC = [settingsStoryboard instantiateInitialViewController];
initialSettingsVC.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
[self presentViewController:initialSettingsVC animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

the stack should now be:

```
1:[welcome]
2:[login]
3:[start]
```

I might get to description in the workflow before I decide to click logout (available on each page), my stack at this point would be

```
1:[welcome]-[login.storyboard]

2:[login]-[login.storyboard]

3:[start]-[processing.storyboard]

4:[images]-[processing.storyboard]

5:[description]-[processing.storyboard]
```

logout should take me back to [welcome], my question is with the storyboards how would I clear the stack back to [welcome] and ensure the login.storyboard is current.

There's a gap in my knowledge here, as I've just gotten back into iphone dev after 6 years or so and not seen these before.

I had thought of just pushing login.storyboard onto the stack but that would just make the stack continue to grow instead of clearing it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use unwind segues.

Add this method in [welcome]:

```
-(IBAction)reset:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue
{
    NSLog(@"Back to Welcome");
}
```

In Interface Builder, create `UIButtons` in [start], [images] and [description] then link each of these buttons to the green "Exit" button of their respective viewControllers and select `reset:` in the pop-up menu that appears.

(See WWDC 2012 session video "Adopting Storyboards in Your App" for more details about unwind segues [starts at 38 minutes].)

Answer (score 1):

You can `pop` back to any arbitrary point in the stack, for example

```
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];         // all the way back to the first view controller
    [self.navigationController popToViewController:self.navigationController.viewControllers[1] animated:YES];  // back to the second view controller 
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];               // back to the previous view controller
```

This answer assumes that storyboard 1 has

- navigation controller
- welcome view controller
- login view controller

and storyboard 2 has

- navigation controller
- start view controller
- images view controller
- description view controller
- finish view controller

Note that the navigation controller in storyboard 2 is never actually instantiated but is needed so that the other view controllers in storyboard 2 can be connected by segues. When navigating from the `login view controller` to the `start view controller` the code should look similar to this

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"SecondStoryboard" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ControllerC"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

Note that this doesn't instantiate the `initialViewController` since that's the navigation controller, and we don't want another navigation controller.  Instead, give the `start` view controller a `Storyboard ID` under the `Identity inspector`, and then instantiate the `start` view controller directly.  After instantiating the `start` view controller, push it onto the existing navigation controller.  You may want to hide the back button if you don't want the user to navigate back to the `login` view controller.